# How to use HibernateCursorItemReader in spring batch

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

In a spring batch job, I have a step in which I want to read data by chunk from the database using Hibernate, process it and write it back to the database. Right now I'm having some trouble setting up the reader :

```java
@EnableBatchProcessing
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.x.y.z.database", "com.x.y.p.database"}, excludeFilters={
        @ComponentScan.Filter(type= FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE, value=ConfigHelperMail.class)})
@EntityScan(basePackages = {"com.x.y.z.database", "com.x.y.p.database"})
@EnableJpaRepositories({"com.x.y.z.database", "com.x.y.p.database"})
public class BatchConfiguration {
    @Autowired
    public JobBuilderFactory jobs;
    @Bean
    public Job job(CustomJobListener listener,
                     @Qualifier("step1") Step step1,
                     @Qualifier("step2") Step step2,
                     @Qualifier("step3") Step step3) {
        return jobs.get("SimpleJobName")
                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .preventRestart()
                .listener(listener)
                .start(step1)
                .next(step2)
                .next(step3)
                .build();
    }
}
```

In `step1` writer I save the data to the database using Hibernate :

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "tmp_z_stepone")
public class StepOneEntity {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "reference")
    private String reference;
    /** Other properties and getters and setters **/
}

@Component
public class StepOneWriter implements ItemWriter<StepOneEntity> {
    @Autowired
    private StepOneService stepOneService;
    @Override
    public void write (List<? extends StepOneEntity> items) throws WriterException {
        stepOneService.saveMany(items);
    }
}
```

`StepOneService` is annotated with `@Service` and it uses a DAO interface that extends `CrudRepository<StepOneEntity, String>` and its `saveMany` method just uses the `save` method from `CrudRepository<StepOneEntity, String>`.

Step 2

```java
@Component
public class StepOne {
    @Autowired
    private StepTwoReader reader;
    @Autowired
    private StepTwoProcessor processor;
    @Autowired
    private StepTwoWriter writer;
    @Bean
    @JobScope
    @Qualifier("step2")
    public Step step2() throws ReaderException {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("step2")
                .<StepOneEntity, StepTwoEntity>chunk(10)
                .reader(reader.read())
                .processor(processor)
                .writer(writer)
                .build();
    }
}

@Component
public class StepTwoReader {
    public ItemReader<OutputControleFormat> read () throws ReaderException {
        HibernateCursorItemReader itemReader = new HibernateCursorItemReader();
        itemReader.setQueryString("from tmp_z_stepone");
        itemReader.setUseStatelessSession(true);
        return itemReader;
    }
}
```

I think I'm missionf some session/ORM configuration but I don't know where, the error is below :

```
org.springframework.batch.item.ItemStreamException: Failed to initialize the reader
    at org.springframework.batch.item.support.AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.open(AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.java:147) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-3.0.8.RELEASE.jar:3.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.item.support.CompositeItemStream.open(CompositeItemStream.java:96) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-3.0.8.RELEASE.jar:3.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.ChunkMonitor.open(ChunkMonitor.java:114) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.8.RELEASE.jar:3.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.item.support.CompositeItemStream.open(CompositeItemStream.java:96) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-3.0.8.RELEASE.jar:3.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep.open(TaskletStep.java:310) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.8.RELEASE.jar:3.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:197) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.8.RELEASE.jar:3.0.8.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333) [spring-aop-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190) [spring-aop-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) [spring-aop-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:133) [spring-aop-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:121) [spring-aop-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) [spring-aop-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213) [spring-aop-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy110.execute(Unknown Source) [na:na]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler.handleStep(SimpleStepHandler.java:148) [spring-batch-core-3.0.8.RELEASE.jar:3.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.handleStep(AbstractJob.java:392) [spring-batch-core-3.0.8.RELEASE.jar:3.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleJob.doExecute(SimpleJob.java:135) [spring-batch-core-3.0.8.RELEASE.jar:3.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:306) [spring-batch-core-3.0.8.RELEASE.jar:3.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:135) [spring-batch-core-3.0.8.RELEASE.jar:3.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50) [spring-core-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:128) [spring-batch-core-3.0.8.RELEASE.jar:3.0.8.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333) [spring-aop-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190) [spring-aop-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) [spring-aop-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration$PassthruAdvice.invoke(SimpleBatchConfiguration.java:127) [spring-batch-core-3.0.8.RELEASE.jar:3.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) [spring-aop-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213) [spring-aop-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy107.run(Unknown Source) [na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.execute(JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.java:211) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.executeLocalJobs(JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.java:227) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.launchJobFromProperties(JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.java:123) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.run(JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.java:117) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:732) [spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:716) [spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.afterRefresh(SpringApplication.java:703) [spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:304) [spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118) [spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107) [spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
    at com.cdn.oxc.signature.ApplicationConfig.main(ApplicationConfig.java:33) [classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.springframework.batch.item.database.HibernateItemReaderHelper.createQuery(HibernateItemReaderHelper.java:141) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-3.0.8.RELEASE.jar:3.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.item.database.HibernateItemReaderHelper.getForwardOnlyCursor(HibernateItemReaderHelper.java:125) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-3.0.8.RELEASE.jar:3.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.item.database.HibernateCursorItemReader.doOpen(HibernateCursorItemReader.java:185) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-3.0.8.RELEASE.jar:3.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.item.support.AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.open(AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.java:144) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-3.0.8.RELEASE.jar:3.0.8.RELEASE]
    ... 46 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 1):

`HibernateCursorItemReader` implements the `InitializingBean` interface, which means that Spring will call its `afterPropertiesSet` on container initialization if it is declared as a bean. However, in your case, the `HibernateCursorItemReader` is not declared as a bean in the application context, it is wrapped in a class (`StepTwoReader`) then created with `reader.read()`.

If you declare the `HibernateCursorItemReader` as a bean with your current code in your `read` method, you should get an `IllegalStateException` with message: "A SessionFactory must be provided". You actually need to configure a `SessionFactory` for your Hibernate reader.

Another option is to use the `HibernateCursorItemReaderBuilder` which will ensure the reader is correctly configured.

Comment: Can you share an example about configuring a `SessionFactory` or using `HibernateCursorItemReaderBuilder` ? I'm new to this. Thank you

Comment: You can find an example of how to configure the session factory as well as how to use the builder here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/master/spring-batch-infrastructure/src/test/java/org/springframework/batch/item/database/builder/HibernateCursorItemReaderBuilderTests.java. Please accept the answer if it answers your question.

Answer (score 1):

```
@StepScope
@Slf4j
@Component
public class CursorItemReader extends HibernateCursorItemReader<ItemEntity> {


    public CursorItemReader(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory,
                            @Value("#{stepExecution}")StepExecution stepExecution) {

       
        this.setName("CursorItemReader");
        this.setSessionFactory(entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager().unwrap(org.hibernate.Session.class).getSessionFactory());
        this.setQueryString("from ItemEntity");
        this.setUseStatelessSession(true);
        this.setFetchSize(5);
    }

    @Override
    public ItemEntity read() throws Exception {
        ItemEntity item = this.doRead();
        return item;
    }

}
```

You can also refer-
https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/reference/html/readersAndWriters.html#HibernateCursorItemReader